# Facade design pattern with interface

Tags: .net, design-patterns, architecture

Can we create facade design pattern using abstract class or Interfaces?

Somone asked me to think on how can we implement facade design pattern using abstract class or Interface. I don't think we can achieve this with abstract class or interface.

Comment: Why not? A facade is basically a class that delegates calls to a subsystem. And this class can be described by an interface (or inherit from an abstract class)

Answer (score 0):

A facade design pattern is designed to abstract away from the details of the other class implementations. If those classes are completely self enclosed, then sure. We can use an `abstract` class with `static` methods.

**Example**

```
public abstract class Animal { }

public class Dog extends Animal
{
    public void bark() { };
}

public class Cat extends Animal
{
    public void meow() { };
}

public abstract class AnimalAdapter {
    public static void speak(Animal animal) {
       if(animal instanceof Dog) { 
          Dog dog = (Dog)animal;
          dog.bark();
       }
       else if(animal instanceof Cat) {
          Cat cat = (Cat)animal;
          cat.meow();
       }
    }
}
```

As you can see, you've created a class `AnimalAdapter` that abstracts away from the specific methods of the `Dog` and `Cat` class, and this class is an `abstract` class in it's own right. It's usage might be something like this:

```
public void doSomething()
{
     AnimalAdapter.speak(new Dog());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what architecture you are using. If you use pure `TDD` following `SRP` with constructor injection, then the answer is not recommended, because every dependency must be injected from the constructor. If you need facade in this case, use abstract (or normal) factory pattern and [`Aggregate Services / Facade Service`](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) instead.

This is because in pure `TDD` and `SRP`, mutable property is not allowed, so additional property in interface is breaking the design. Such as:

```
public interface IFacade{
    IClass1 Class1{get;set;} // not allowed
    void DoFacade();
}
```

Is not permitted.

However if you do not following it, then the mutable dependency at interface-level can be permitted.